# Prisma can't deploy with local Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, prisma, prisma-graphql

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: 'http://javad:javad@localhost:27017/admin'
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
    restart: always
    # Uncomment the next two lines to connect to your your database from outside the Docker environment, e.g. using a database GUI like Compass
    # ports:
    # - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: prisma
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo:/var/lib/mongo
volumes:
  mongo:
```

And my prisma.yml:

```
endpoint: http://192.168.99.100:4466
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
databaseType: document
```

When i say

> prisma deploy

i get this massage:

> ERROR: No cluster could be found for workspace '*' and cluster
>   'default'
>
> {   "data": {
>       "generateClusterToken": null   },   "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "No cluster could be found for workspace '*' and cluster 'default'",
>         "locations": [
>           {
>             "line": 3,
>             "column": 9
>           }
>         ],
>         "path": [
>         ],
>         "code": 222
>       }   ],   "status": 200 }
>
> Get in touch if you need help: https://slack.prisma.io To get more
>   detailed output, run $ export DEBUG="*" (node:17204) [DEP0066]
>   DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please check your prisma and prisma cli version and update if possible, since there was a bug in a previous version of the prisma cli (see https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4215).

After that please verify that the endpoint specified in the prisma.yml is indeed accessible and the port is forwarded correctly. Please test if the problem persists when changing endpoint to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Lastly you can try to set the `managementApiSecret` in the docker config and add `PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET` to the env file.